# Laravel Where and OrWhere multiple conditions

Tags: laravel

I have the following query:

```
$items = UserItems::join('items','items.id','=','user_items.item_id')
            ->where('user_id','=',$this->id)
            ->where('quantity','>',0)
            ->where('items.type',"stones")
            ->orWhere('items.type',"fish")
            ->get();
```

My problem is that this query returns the items of ALL users instead of the given `user_Id.`. It's because the orWhere applies on all of the `where's` but I need it to apply only on this:

```
->where('items.type',"stones")
                ->orWhere('items.type',"fish")
```

How I can fix the query to return only the given $this->id user items?

Comment: I guess another option, as opposed to `orWhere`, could be to use the `whereIn` operator like: `->whereIn('items.type', ["stones", "fish"])`.

Answer (score 6):

Laravel supports [`Advanced Where Clauses`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses) like such:

```
$items = UserItems::join('items','items.id','=','user_items.item_id')
    ->where('user_id','=',$this->id)
    ->where('quantity','>',0)
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('items.type',"stones")
            ->orWhere('items.type',"fish");
    })
    ->get();
```

I guess another option (cleaner, easier to read IMO), as opposed to using `orWhere`, could be to use the [`whereIn` operator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses) like:

```
$items = UserItems::join('items','items.id','=','user_items.item_id')
    ->where('user_id','=',$this->id)
    ->where('quantity','>',0)
    ->whereIn('items.type', ["stones", "fish"])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

when we have to use any variable in where/orwhere clause when using function then we have to pass those in use variable

```
    `$acc_exist = Account::where('group_id', $fgn_grp_id)->
    where('company_id', session('company_id'))->
    where(function ($query) use($acc_name, $acc_num) {
    $query->where('name', $acc_name)->orWhere('number', $acc_num);
    })->first();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure, something like the following:

```
$userId = $this->id;
$items = UserItems::join('items','items.id','=','user_items.item_id')
->where('user_id','=', $userId)
->where('quantity','>',0)
->where(function($query) {
    $query
    ->where('items.type',"stones")
    ->orWhere('items.type',"fish");
})
->get();
```