# Laravel OrWhere having two conditions is not so obvious

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

Why in Eloquent a simple query as this one is not working?

```
$matches = DB::table("matches")
   ->where(["team_a"=> $request->tid, "match_tipo"=>3])
   ->orWhere(["team_a"=> $request->tid, "match_tipo"=>3])
   ->first();
```

According to with other examples here on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254902/laravel-where-and-orwhere-multiple-conditions), I should use a query in Where like:

```
$matches = DB::table("matches")
 ->where(["match_tipo"=>3])
 ->where(function($query, $request) {
      $query->where('team_h',$request->tid)
            ->orWhere('team_a',$request->tid);
      })
->first();
```

But I should pass a second parameter ($request).

How is the simplest way to do this query?

Comment: update your question with what you exactly want to do. which fields are mandatory to match, and which are optional??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this as like this.

`->where(["match_tipo"=>3])` this will be `->where("match_tipo",3)` and `use($tid)` after query.

```
$tid = $request->tid; 
$matches = DB::table("matches")
 ->where("match_tipo",3)
 ->where(function($query) use($tid) {
      $query->where('team_h',$tid)
            ->orWhere('team_a',$tid);
      })
->get();
```

Comment: oh yes! I forgot "use"! Thanks very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

while using the **Callback or Closure** as the **where** function Parameter you will only the one argument which is **Current Object**

Methods Can used to Pass the **$request**

> Method One

```
$matches = DB::table("matches")
 ->where(["match_tipo"=>3])
 ->where(function($query) use ($request) {
      $query->where('team_h',$request->tid)
            ->orWhere('team_a',$request->tid);
      })
->first();
```

> Method Two

```
$matches = DB::table("matches")
    ->where('match_tipo','=',3)
    ->when($request->tid,function($query) use ($request) {
        return $query->where('team_h',$request->tid)
              ->orWhere('team_a',$request->tid);
        })
   ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
$matches = DB::table("matches")
   ->where('match_tipo',3)
   ->whereRaw('team_a = "'.$request->tid.'" OR team_h = "'.$request->tid.'"')
   ->first();
```